# The 'Microsoft .Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I'm trying to import some data from excel into a database . i got the following code from http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/05/31/2976.aspx . I have a x86 arhitecture so that's not the problem . when i run the code the program says at `connection.Open();` that The 'Microsoft     .Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. Any ideas ?

```
 string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft
    .Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C://suc.xls;Extended
    Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;""";

// Create Connection to Excel Workbook
using (OleDbConnection connection =
             new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
{
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand
            ("Select ID,Data FROM [Data$]", connection);

    connection.Open();

    // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet
    using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // SQL Server Connection String
        string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True";

        // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                   new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "ExcelData";
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the code on a 64 bit machine, and its a web project, then open IIS, right click on the Application pool and click on Advanced settings. Set the second property from the top: Enable 32 bit application to True, that should fix the problem.

Comment: i have specified that i am using a 32bit machine

Answer (score 0):

I assume that both that the correct version of `Excel` and the `Interop.Excel.dll` file is present on the machine generating this error? Since the Jet provider is found in the interop DLL I think that is the most likely explanation.

Comment: the excel version is now correct but that it still shows the same error. the Interop.Excel.dll isn't requested